# Alexandrov embedness and branch points

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let assume that $\Sigma_n$ is a sequence of compact surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of fixed genus. We assume that the surfaces are Alexandrov embedded, that is to say there exits an immersion $i_n$ from $\Omega$ a $3$-manifold into $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\partial \Omega$ is topologically like  $\Sigma_n$ and such that $i_n(\partial \Omega) = \Sigma_n$.

Then we assume that $\Sigma_n$ converges to $\Sigma$ in the sense that around each point there exists local conformal parametrization $u_n :\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $u_n$ converge in $C^2_{loc}(\mathbb{D})$ to $u :\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

Is that possible that $\Sigma$ get branch point? i.e. locally $u$ looks like $z \mapsto z^k$.

This question come from constant mean curvature surface theory in some pertubative setting. Hence I can assume that the branch point are isolated.

For instance: does there exists a sequence of smooth Alexandrov embedded surfaces which converge in the sens  defined above to $\omega\circ z\mapsto z^3$ where $\omega$ is the inverse of the stereographic projection?

Comment: I think, you are confusing two things: You defined convergence of embedded surfaces, but your question is about maps. Lastly, your maps u are from the plane to the real line. How do you get maps from complex plane to itself as a limit? I do not see how to make sense of this.

Comment: I reformulate the problem on mathoverflow. is this more clear?http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180240/branch-point-and-alexandrov-embeddedness

Comment: I understand now: The question at MO is clearer.